Poor performance of SWiftUI table animation when changing the number of elements in the source object
In my app, the sidebar contains data "filters" for the table. DetailView contains the table itself. When selecting items in the sidebar, there is a noticeable delay before the table is visually updated.
Profiling showed that the problem is in the calculation of the height of the table rows. I tried to fix the height of the all table column views with .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true), but this did not help.
Maybe there is some way to force the table not to recalculate the row height, since it is known in advance and is the same for all rows?
Code
Model
@Observable
final class Item: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var value: Int
    var name: String
    var c1: String
    var c2: String
    var c3: String
    var c4: String
    var c5: String
    var c6: String
    var c7: String
    var c8: String
    var c9: String
    
    init(value: Int) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.value = value
        self.name = "name_" + "\(Int.random(in: 0...9))"
        self.c1 = "\(UUID())"
        self.c2 = "\(UUID())"
        self.c3 = "\(UUID())"
        self.c4 = "\(UUID())"
        self.c5 = "\(UUID())"
        self.c6 = "\(UUID())"
        self.c7 = "\(UUID())"
        self.c8 = "\(UUID())"
        self.c9 = "\(UUID())"

    }
}

@MainActor
@Observable
final class AppModel {
    
    var items: [Item]
    var selectedItem1: Set<UUID> = .init()
    
    var selectedFilters: Set<String> = []
    
    var subject: CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never> = .init(0)
    
    init() {
        var items: [Item] = []
        for i in 0...1000 {
            items.append(Item(value: i))
        }
        self.items = items
    }
    
    func updateValue() {
        let index = Int.random(in: 0..<items.count)
        items[index].value = Int.random(in: 200...300)
    }
    
    func startPolling() {
        // imitate a poll from the network
        Task {
            let asymcSequence = subject
                .debounce(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
                .values
            
            for await _ in asymcSequence {
                updateValue()
                subject.send(subject.value + 1)
            }
        }
    }
}

View
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(AppModel.self) private var appModel
    @State private var sortOrder = [KeyPathComparator(\Item.name)]
    
    private var sideBarItems: [String] {
        let set = Set(appModel.items.map({ $0.name })).sorted(by: <)
        return Array(set)
    }
    
    private var items: [Item] {
        appModel.items.filter({ appModel.selectedFilters.contains($0.name )})
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var appModel = appModel
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $appModel.selectedFilters) {
                ForEach(sideBarItems, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                        .tag(item)
                        .badge(appModel.items.filter({ $0.name == item }).count)
                    
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Table(of: Item.self, selection: $appModel.selectedItem1, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
                TableColumn("value") { item in
                    Text("\(item.value)")
                        //.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                }
                TableColumn("c1", value: \.c1)
                TableColumn("c2", value: \.c2)
                TableColumn("c3", value: \.c3)
                TableColumn("c4", value: \.c4)
                TableColumn("c5", value: \.c5)
                TableColumn("c6", value: \.c6)
                TableColumn("c7", value: \.c7)
                TableColumn("c8", value: \.c8)
                TableColumn("c9", value: \.c9)
            } rows: {
                ForEach(items)
            }
        }
        .animation(.smooth, value: items.count)
        .frame(minWidth: 1000, minHeight: 640)
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            appModel.startPolling()
        }
    }
}


"the problem is in the calculation of the height of the table rows" which method specifically? If it is a NSTableView method then there is likely nothing you can do. fixedSize doesn't help because that isn't really what fixedSize does. I'd try frame(height: 50). Though at the end of the day you might have to use NSTableView directly.

@Sweeper, Yes, the row height calculation is done in the NSTableView method. I tried to limit the row height with .frame(height:... but it didn't have any effect.
